# Custom directive push children text in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a custom directive on a div

```
<div appAutoTypingText>
  <p>on va mettre un premier texte</p>
  <p>Puis un second texte</p>
</div>
```

I want my directive get the text inside the p tag and push them in a array like this

```
['on va mettre un premier texte', 'Puis un second texte']
```

How can i have this result please?
I cant find in Element ref an array of the children i just have a NodeList or a HTMLcollection

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sharing enough of your code for me to tell what's going on, but my assumption is you're trying to dig into the content (to find the p tags) before they are available. Here is a simple demo for how you could go about it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zeu51h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirectiveDirective implements OnInit{
  private readonly _elementRef: ElementRef;
  public items: string[];
  constructor(_el: ElementRef) {
    this._elementRef = _el;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const pTags = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('p');
    this.items = [];
    if (pTags) {
      pTags.forEach( p => this.items.push(p.innerText));
      console.log(this.items);
    }
  }

}
```

**Usage**

```
<div appMyDirective>
  <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  <p>Something else</p>
</div>
```